# Test if modified file time is within 2 days in Python

Tags: python

How can I test whether a file has been modified within the past 2 days or less using Python?

```
import os
file_time = os.path.getmtime('test1.jpg')

# pseudo...
if file_time <= ??:
     return true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
import time
difference = (time.time() - file_time) / (60 * 60 * 24)
if difference <= 2:
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import time

def is_modified_in_2_days(m_time):
    seconds_in_two_days = 2 * 60 * 60 * 24
    current_time = time.time() # current time in epoch second
    return current_time - m_time <= seconds_in_two_days
```

See: [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html?highlight=time.time#time.time)